# Is this dot puzzle solvable?

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle, hamiltonian-path

Is it possible to connect all the dots with one line without touching the same point, going diagonally, or touching the black line?

• • • • • • • 
| • • • • • • 
• • • • • • • 
• • • • • • • 
• • • • • • •

If it is, how can we show this mathematically?

Comment: By one line, do you mean one loop? If it was by one line, it would always work, no matter what, making the problem trivial.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Color the dots in a check pattern. You'll see the number of the dots in one color is $18$, and the number of the dots in the other color is $16$. Note that one always has to go from one color to the other color.